# Why does EF Core One-to-Many relationship collection return null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This may seem like a duplicate question [EF Core One-to-Many relationship list returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210832/ef-core-one-to-many-relationship-list-returns-null), but the answer to that question didn't help me. My situation:

```
public class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public IEnumerable<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}

public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public Section Section { get; set; }
}
```

But I have not implemented the `OnModelCreating` method in DbContext because in that case, errors occurs with users identity. There are topics in the database with the specified SectionId. But no matter how I try to get the section, I get null in the `Topics` property. For example:

```
var section = _dbContext.Sections.Include(s => s.Topics).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
```

What is the reason for this problem? Have I declared something wrong? Or maybe there is a problem in creating a topic?

**UPDATE**

I tried to override the `OnModelCreating` method this way:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Section>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Topics)
    .WithOne(t => t.Section);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

And this way:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Section>()
    .HasMany(s => s.Topics)
    .WithOne(t => t.Section)
    .HasForeignKey(prop => prop.SectionId);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I also added the virtual attribute to the dependencies again. It did not help. Added a test migration (thought there might be something wrong with the database structure), but the migration was empty.

**SOLUTION**

As a result, I solved the problem with a crutch:

```
var section = _dbContext.Sections.Include(s => s.Topics).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);

if (section == null)
{
    return Error();
}

section.Topics = _dbContext.Topics.Where(t => t.SectionId == section.Id).Include(t => t.Author).ToList();

foreach(var topic in section.Topics)
{
    topic.Author = _dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == topic.AuthorId);
    topic.Posts = _dbContext.Posts.Where(t => t.TopicId == topic.Id).ToList();
}
```

As you can see, I had to explicitly get data from the dbContext and assign them to the appropriate properties. `Include` method calls can be deleted because they do not perform the desired action.

Comment: the dbcontext is you create yourself or efcore generated? if you created it yourself, then you better let efcore generate it for you. it will work 100%.

Comment: @Asherguru I'm using `IdentityDbContext`. So I should split the db context into two parts  (identification and auto-generated context)?

Comment: Try making Topics `public virtual ICollection<Topic> topics {get;set;}`. The virtual is needed to support child loading. You may want to specify the version of EF core you are using because the behavior of child collection loading has changed across the various versions.

Comment: @AnthonyMinchenko I'm not sure as I didn't use IdentityDbContext. You can check if efcore has another command to generate IdentityDbContext automatically. Or wait for better solution here.

Comment: not directly related to your question, but it really is not a good idea to have the same context for managing identity and your data. if I were you, I would have a separate context, separate database, and code generated by EF Core. it may not solve this problem, and also potential problems you may face tomorrow due to sharing context with identity.

Comment: @JimWooley I initially made this property virtual, but then I assumed that the problem might be related to it and removed this attribute. I'm using the EF Core 3.1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the guide on this link https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading

1. Install the *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions* package into the project containing your model classes:

```
    [Package Manager Console]
    install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions

    [Dotnet CLI]
    add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions
```

2. Alter the principal entity to include

- a `using` directive for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure`
- a field for the `ILazyLoader` instance
- an empty constructor, and one that takes an `ILazyLoader` as a parameter (which can be private, if you prefer)
- a field for the collection navigation property
- a getter in the public property that uses the `ILazyLoader.Load` method

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

public class Author
{
    private readonly ILazyLoader _lazyLoader;

    public Author()
    {
    }

    public Author(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)
    {
        _lazyLoader = lazyLoader;
    }

    private List<Book> _books;

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    public List<Book> Books
    {
        get => _lazyLoader.Load(this, ref _books);
        set => _books = value;
    }
}
```

**The solution in the answer will not work in case of many-to-many relationship.**

Answer (score 2):

Several suggestions:

1. Try to make your Section define Topics as ICollection rather than IEnumerable and virtual so that they can be lazy loaded if necessary

```
public class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
}
```

2. In your solution sample, you should be able to leverage EF Core's ThenInclude method to get the Sections, Topics, and Authors in one fell swoop:

```
var section = _dbContext.Sections
    .Include(s => s.Topics)
    .ThenInclude(t => t.Authors)
    .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);
```

However to get the collection of authors and posts in the same child collection, you may want to consider a custom projection into a new type. EF Core 3.1 should piece all of this into a single query. Earlier versions of Core would break it apart into multiple database queries depending on the version and exact syntax you used. Something like:

```
var items = 
    from section in _dbContext.Sections
    from topic in section.Topics
    select new {
       section.Name,
       topic.Description,
       Authors = topic.Authors.ToList(),
       Posts = topic.Posts.ToList()
    };
```

Comment: 1. I tried. Also tried to set `List` data type. Nothing.
2. What's the point of using `ThenInclude` if even `Include` doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks I had a similar issue and "ThenInclude" fixed it