# Retrieve from DB and Include Multiple ICollections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, module, include

I'm working with EF6. I have a module with multiple `ICollection`s. My solution to retrieve the lists of objects is similar but I find it dumb, as I need to rewrite this on all the pages where I need `IEnumerable<BookModel> GetAllBook`.

```
 IEnumerable<BookModel> GetAllBook = DBContext.BookModels.Include(x => x.AssociatedNames).Include(e => e.BlogModel);
```

I read several topics on this but these stood out. From what I understood, the answer is written in the `DbContext.cs` with the `DbSet`s. But does the `BookModule` have a complete list of example authors? Without the need of including another time?

[Include several references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072360/include-several-references-on-the-second-level)

I also read
[Why does EF Core One-to-Many relationship collection return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64094376/why-does-ef-core-one-to-many-relationship-collection-return-null)

```
public class BookModel
{
    [Key]
    public int BookModelID{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AssociatedNames>? AssociatedNames { get; set; }
    public virtual List<BookModel>? relatedSeries { get; set; }
    public virtual List<BookModel>? RecommendedBookModels { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AuthorModel>? Authormodels { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArtistModel>? ArtistModels { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VoiceActorModel>? VoiceActors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GenresModel>? GenresModels { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TagModel>? TagsModels { get; set; }
}
```

My question is there a way for my `bookModel` have the complete lists of objects without needing to use `Include` again, and again.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need in this cas is the AutoInclude feature introduced with EF6 , so You will have to go into the **OnModelCreating** Method and add the following lines ( you update that to your use case , depends on which related entities you want to be autoIncluded ):

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookModel>().Navigation(e => e.Authormodels).AutoInclude();
    modelBuilder.Entity<BookModel>().Navigation(e => e.Artistmodels).AutoInclude();
```

and if , for a specific cas you need only the books , and you want to get rid of the autoIncludes , then us can use the **IgnoreAutoIncludes** feature like below :

```
    var books = context.BookModels.IgnoreAutoIncludes().ToList();
```

Fore more details about this you can look up this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager) or [this video](https://www.google.com/search?q=EF%20Include%20related%20data%20bydefault%20&sxsrf=ALiCzsbyJ2F0Nv5oFm-DkUAxxcGe8MhWmA%3A1671978962823&ei=0l-oY8voMcjrgAbe17yoCA&ved=0ahUKEwjLmZqB_5T8AhXINcAKHd4rD4UQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=EF%20Include%20related%20data%20bydefault%20&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIHCCEQoAEQCjIECCEQCjoKCAAQRxDWBBCwAzoFCAAQgAQ6BggAEBYQHjoICAAQFhAeEA86BQgAEIYDOgUIIRCgAToICCEQFhAeEB06CAgAEAgQHhANSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUPMFWOcfYKUhaAFwAXgAgAG_AYgBiBmSAQQwLjIzmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#fpstate=ive&scso=_LWCoY6zeBJuL9u8P_sajwAo_49:364&vld=cid:2a88be7a,vid:7HuOivcr6Mg,st:802)

Comment: This was exactly what i was searching for! Thank you